# Is there any way to get current time in nanoseconds using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, time, precision, time-precision

So, I know I can get current time in milliseconds using JavaScript. But, is it possible to get the current time in nanoseconds instead?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Achieve microsecond accuracy in most browsers using:

```js
window.performance.now()
```

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now()
- http://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/
- https://caniuse.com/high-resolution-time

Comment: The 'webkit' prefix was removed around Chrome 24.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now()?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FPerformanceTiming.now

Comment: Note that window.performance.now() returns the time relative to the navigationStart of the page rather than to the UNIX epoch.
See my answer below for code snippet for current time.

Comment: Yet, microseconds are not nanoseconds, so `performance.now()` is useless here.

Comment: Apparently browsers don’t actually return nanosecond precision due to security considerations, according to the hint on the MDN site you linked: “[B]rowsers currently round the results to varying degrees. […] Some browsers may also slightly randomize the timestamp.”

Comment: "The performance.now() method returns a DOMHighResTimeStamp, measured in milliseconds", according to the link you posted. Milliseconds are not nanoseconds.

Answer (score 11):

Building on Jeffery's answer, to get an absolute time-stamp (as the OP wanted) the code would be:

```
var TS = window.performance.timing.navigationStart + window.performance.now();
```

result is in millisecond units but is a floating-point value reportedly "*accurate to one thousandth of a millisecond*".

Comment: **WARNING** `performance.timing.navigationStart` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

In Server side environments like Node.js you can use the following function to get time in nanosecond

```js
function getNanoSecTime() {
  var hrTime = process.hrtime();
  return hrTime[0] * 1000000000 + hrTime[1];
}
```

Also get micro seconds in a similar way as well:

```js
function getMicSecTime() {
  var hrTime = process.hrtime();
  return hrTime[0] * 1000000 + parseInt(hrTime[1] / 1000);
}
```

Comment: This does NOT return the CURRENT timestamp when using Node 7.4.0 and 7.5.0.

Comment: I happened to see this in api of `process.hrtime`: "These times are relative to an arbitrary time in the past, and not related to the time of day and therefore not subject to clock drift. The primary use is for measuring performance between intervals".

Answer (score 9):

## Milliseconds since the UNIX epoch, *with the microseconds resolution.*

`performance.timing.navigationStart` has been **deprecated**! Use the following instead:

```js
(performance.now() + performance.timeOrigin)
```

---

#### Relevant quotes from [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-2)

> This specification defines an API that provides the time origin, and current time in sub-millisecond resolution, such that it is not subject to system clock skew or adjustments.
>
> The ***`timeOrigin`*** attribute *MUST* return a `DOMHighResTimeStamp` representing the high resolution time of the *time origin timestamp* for the *relevant global object* of the `Performance` object.
>
> The ***time origin timestamp*** is the high resolution time value at which *time origin* is zero.
>
> The ***time origin*** is the time value from which time is measured
>
> The ***`now()`*** method *MUST* return the *current high resolution time*.
>
> The ***current high resolution time*** is the high resolution time from the time origin to the present time (typically called “now”).

---

#### Note that actually it is not *that* accurate for security reasons <sub>(to prevent side-channel attacks)</sub>

> This specification defines an API that provides sub-millisecond time resolution, which is more accurate than the previously available millisecond resolution exposed by `DOMTimeStamp`. However, even without this new API an attacker may be able to obtain high-resolution estimates through repeat execution and statistical analysis. To ensure that the new API does not significantly improve the accuracy or speed of such attacks, the minimum resolution of the `DOMHighResTimeStamp` type should be inaccurate enough to prevent attacks: **the current minimum recommended resolution is no less than 5 microseconds** and, where necessary, should be set higher by the User Agent to address privacy and security concerns due to architecture or software constraints, or other considerations.

Comment: This is the closest as you can possibly get.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that it returns using decimals. So it is still milliseconds, so we don't have to go through that error.

Answer (score 6):

Yes! Try the excellent sazze's [**nano-time**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano-time)

```
let now = require('nano-time');
now(); // '1476742925219947761' (returns as string due to JS limitation)
```

Comment: NB -- for node only -- uses `process.hrtime()` (@TahsinTurkoz), and then calculates an absolute time from that.

Comment: After installing `nano-time`, this gives me `Uncaught TypeError: process.hrtime is not a function`

Answer (score 4):

No. There is not a chance you will get nanosecond accuracy at the JavaScript layer.

If you're trying to benchmark some very quick operation, put it in a loop that runs it a few thousand times.

Comment: +1 ...and why would you want to? If it needs to be *that* precise it should probably not be JavaScript in the first place. *PS: Hey, mod: deleting flame comments should leave the valid comments intact. Just an idea.*

Comment: Do you know *who* delete all the comments?

Comment: I know, necropost.

I just did. start millisecond timer, run the function 10,000,000 times, stop millisecond timer, and divide the execution time by 10,000,000.

I was timing the timer itself to calibrate it, as running the timer and typecasting/concatenating the output takes time. Takes 3 microseconds on my computer, give or take about 200 nanoseconds.

Comment: Of course, knowing the execution time down to the last 0.00000001 seconds isn't really necessary; unless that functions going to run 1,000,000,000 times.

Comment: @evandentremont Microseconds are an entire _three_ orders of magnitude above nanoseconds!

Comment: Resurrecting this discussion, benchmarks aren't the only use case for time precision. There are some algorithms where it may be needed, and if I want to run it on a browser, JS is a necessity.

Comment: @EduardoMelo For example, LRU replacement in a page fault simulator (a project I'm working on now). Millisecond precision isn't good enough because the code runs *too fast* and the timestamp on my pages all have the same values per 1k pages or so...

Comment: @ChrisCirefice There’s no need to use wall clock time for paging algorithms. Use a simple counter instead.

Comment: @bleistift2 That's what I ended up doing ;)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript records time in milliseconds, so you won't be able to get time to that precision. The [smart-aleck](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smart-aleck) answer is to "multiply by 1,000,000".

Comment: This is actually exactly what I wanted, I don't actually care about the nanosecond time just need  a Date to go into the correct format ;)