# High resolution date and time representation in JSON/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net, json, datetime, time

Is there an accepted way to represent high resolution timestamps in JSON and/or JavaScript?

Ideally, I would like it to support at least 100 ns resolution, since that would make the server code a bit simpler (since the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) DateTime resolution is 100 ns as well).

I found a lot of questions dealing with manipulating high-resolution timers and such (which is not possible, apparently), but I simply need to represent it somehow, in an application API.

This is for an API built in [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) style using JSON, so actually *measuring* time in this resolution is not required. However, I would like to transfer and use (potentially in JavaScript) the timestamp in its full resolution (100 ns, since this is .NET).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In light of your clarification, isn't your timestamp just a really big integer? The current timestamp is `1329826212`. If you want nanosecond precision, we are just talking about like 9 more digits: `1329826212000000000`. That is a number that JavaScript can easily handle. Just send it over as:

```
myobject = {
    "time": 1329826212000000000
}
```

It should be perfectly fine. I just tried doing some arithmetic operations on it, division by a large number and multiplication by the same. There is no loss of value.

JavaScript supports a huge range of floating point numbers, but guarantees integral accuracy from `-2^53 to 2^53`. So I think you are good to go.

**UPDATE**
I'm sorry, I just re-read your question. You wish to represent it? Well, one thing I can think of is to extract the last 9 digits (additional precision beyond second granularity) and show them to be the decimal part of the number. You may even wish to extract the last 6 digis (additional precision beyond the millisecond granularity).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using a plain old integer, but wasn't sure if there was some commonly agreed solution already. Integers will do fine :)

Answer (score 3):

The [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) only has millisecond precision.

However, if you are just looking for a standard format to encode nanosecond precision times, an [ISO 8601 format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) will allow you to define nanoseconds as fractions of seconds:

> Decimal fractions may also be added to any of the three time elements. A decimal point, either a comma or a dot (without any preference as stated most recently in resolution 10 of the 22nd General Conference CGPM in 2003), is used as a separator between the time element and its fraction. A fraction may only be added to the lowest order time element in the representation. To denote "14 hours, 30 and one half minutes", do not include a seconds figure. Represent it as "14:30,5", "1430,5", "14:30.5", or "1430.5". There is no limit on the number of decimal places for the decimal fraction. However, the number of decimal places needs to be agreed to by the communicating parties.

---

There is a trick used by [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/) and [benchmarkjs.com](http://benchmarkjs.com/) that uses a small Java applet that exposes Java's nanosecond timer.

See Stack Overflow question *[Is there any way to get current time in nanoseconds using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002808/is-there-any-way-to-get-current-time-in-nanoseconds-using-javascript)*.

Comment: This does not answer the question, since I only need to transfer the timestamp, not actually measure anything in JavaScript. Clarified the question as well.

Comment: ISO8601 format is a good solution. I'll probably go with integers though, since it seems to be a bit simpler to use and in this case human-readability is not important.