# Trigger javascript to run in 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, html, timer, scripting

How do I get a script to run in my browser with a timer of at least 15 minutes? Right now I'm running into an issue where standard browsers throttle time once a page becomes inactive, which is throwing out my timer. I can't figure out how to [integrate a webworker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293326/implementing-timer-in-javascript-using-web-workers) although this seems like it could be a solution.

```
const timer = 1000 * 60 * 15

setTimeout(test, timer)

function test() {
    console.log("worked");
}
```

Is there another, simpler way to run the test function after 15 minutes other than a webworker? Or is there a video/tutorial that might help me figure out webworkers?

Comment: Maybe Using Nodejs.

Comment: It's throttled, but not stopped completely IIRC - are you doing anything CPU intensive? If so, don't, and see if it makes a difference. Heavy work in inactive tabs isn't allowed, but very light work might be OK - though the timeout time might not be precise

Comment: Whatever you intend to do after 15 minutes can wait until the page moves to the foreground, right?